# PyInquirer with subprocess Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

My goal is simple, I have two scripts A and B and both of them use PyInquirer to handle input from the user.

Script a.py:

```
from PyInquirer import prompt

    def do():
        questions = [
            {
                'type': 'input',
                'name': 'inputa1',
                'message': 'inputa1',
            }
        ]
        answers = prompt(questions)

        # call b.py

        if output_from_b == 1:
            # do something AAA
        else:
            # do something BBB

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        do()
```

And script b.py is almost the same :

```
from PyInquirer import prompt

def do():
    questions = [
        {
            'type': 'input',
            'name': 'inputb1',
            'message': 'inputb1',
        }
    ]
    answers = prompt(questions)
    return answers["inputb1"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do()
```

As you can see that what I want to do is call b.py from a.py and get the user input from b.py and then continue in a.py with the output result.

I tried :

```
f = os.popen("python3 b.py")
```

to call b.py but got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 27, in <module>
    do()
  File "b.py", line 22, in do
    answers = prompt(questions)
  File "python3.7/site-packages/PyInquirer/prompt.py", line 75, in prompt
    eventloop=eventloop)
  File "python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts.py", line 576, in run_application
    output=create_output(true_color=true_color))
  File "python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts.py", line 126, in create_output
    ansi_colors_only=ansi_colors_only, term=term)
  File "python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/terminal/vt100_output.py", line 424, in from_pty
    assert stdout.isatty()
AssertionError
```

I am not sure where gose wrong or is there any other way to get this done.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to used a method class called like this:

```
#import class
classe_call = getattr(importlib.import_module('package.myclassB', 'myclassB')
#create object
myObject = class_call() #you can use param 
#call method
getattr(myObject, do)()
```